# Web Scraping an element that does not appear in beatifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to extract all the courses information from [Udacity Catalog Webiste](https://www.udacity.com/courses/all). 
When I try to extract the price from any course page it returns a `null months access` and an empty value like here:

[the Data Analyst course in the example](https://www.udacity.com/course/data-analyst-nanodegree--nd002)

```
page_req = requests.get('https://www.udacity.com/course/data-analyst-nanodegree--nd002')
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_req.content, 'html.parser')
page_soup.find('div', class_='price-cards').find('div', class_='price-card bundle')
```

```
<div class="price-card bundle"><div class="flag"><p class="flag__text">10% OFF</p></div><div 
class="price-info"><div class="price-info__deal" hidden="">BEST DEAL</div><div class="title h6">null 
months access</div><div class="price"><span class="price__payable"><span class="skeleton 
skeleton__default"><span style="width:100px"> </span></span></span><span class="price__label"><span 
class="current-price"> per month</span></span></div><p class="blurb">Start learning today! Switch to 
the monthly price afterwards if more time is needed.</p><div class="enroll-button__container"></div> 
</div></div>
```

So how can I get the price of the courses?

> Note: The price changes from a country to another. (i.e: In USA it's
> Dollar and Italy it's EURO)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to web-scrape modern sites is by observing the Network traffic. You can do this by opening your browsers Developer Tools [or press Ctrl + Shift + I]. Select Network, mark Preserve log and Disable cache. Next filter only XHR. Reload the page and observe the network calls.

When I called your URI, the web browser made a GET call to [Udacity URI](https://braavos.udacity.com/api/prices?item=urn:x-udacity:item:nd-unit:10153&price_sheet=regular&anonymous_id=e546f01d-4d81-4def-a2a8-160c131458ea&currency=USD). Simulate that call with Python:

```py
from requests import Session

with Session() as httpx:

    URI = 'https://braavos.udacity.com/api/prices'

    params = dict(item='urn:x-udacity:item:nd-unit:10153',
                  price_sheet='regular',
                  currency='USD',
                 )
    response = httpx.get(url=URI, params=params)
    data = response.json()

print(type(data)) # dict
print(data) # dict and thus you can access data as you would dicts

# examples
print(data['results'][0]['payment_plans']['upfront_recurring']['description'])
# 'one time payment of $1,436 USD, followed by $399 USD every 1 month'

print(data['results'][0]['payment_plans']['recurring']['description'])
# '$399 USD every 1 month'
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks for your help. But I want to extract all the prices of the 250 course. By this method, I have to open every course page to get the `nd-unit` to pass it in the `requests.Session.get()`. Is there any method to get automatically all the `nd-unit` variables of each course to extract the prices?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script. I have implemented the script for https://www.udacity.com/course/data-analyst-nanodegree--nd002 using the **API** way one of the best way to get the data from end point. You can do it by checking in the network section of developer tools just press `CTRL+SHIFT+I` and in network filter on XHR to see all the **API** calls. Using requests you can hit the API and it will send back the result which you have to convert in to **JSON** format.

**Benefits of using API url requesting:**

1. Less code.
2. Reliable and Less errors.
3. Get the response considerably fast.
4. Easily accessible.

If you look at the script it is right now extracting payment plans which you wanted to **scrape** recurring and upfront recurring. The same way you can access anything in the **JSON** result like : promotion, original prices etc. Also i have made the URL dynamic you can pass the abbreviation of any country currency and it will give you the result. For example:- for USA i have passed **USD**, for Italy or Europe you can pass **EUR** in the currency variable in **capital only**.

```
import json
import requests
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

def scrape_prices():    

    currency = 'USD'
    url = 'https://braavos.udacity.com/api/prices?item=urn:x-udacity:item:nd-unit:10153&price_sheet=regular&anonymous_id=ae9be6e5-97af-48ee-ab3d-63456a8cb38f&currency=' + currency 
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get(url,verify=False)
    result = json.loads(response.text) 
    extracted_payment_plans_recurring = result['results'][0]['payment_plans']['recurring']
    extracted_payment_plan_upfront = result['results'][0]['payment_plans']['upfront_recurring']
    print('-' * 100)
    print('Payment Plans Recurring: ',extracted_payment_plans_recurring)
    print('-' * 100)
    print('Payment Plans Up front Recurring: ',extracted_payment_plan_upfront)
    print('-' * 100)
```

Recurring payment plans result
[image: Recurring payment plans result]
Upfront recurring payment plans result
[image: Upfront recurring payment plans result]
API url from the UDACITY website
[image: API url from the UDACITY website]
JSON result of prices
[image: JSON result of prices]

Comment: It worked, thanks for your help. But I want to extract all the prices of the 250 course. By this method, I have to open every course page to get the `nd-unit` to pass it in the `requests.Session.get()`. Is there any method to get automatically all the `nd-unit` variables of each course to extract the prices?

Comment: Can you give the link which contains all the courses list?